# Way to add checkbox checked event to cross out in list

Tags: reactjs

I wanted to cross out an item in a list when the checkbox is checked. Is there a way to apply it?

Thank you

```
class ToDoList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ol>
                {this.props.data.map(list => {
                    return (
                        <ol style={{
                            textDecoration: completed ? 'line-through' : 'none'
                          }}> 
                          <input type="checkbox" key={list.uuid} ></input>{list.text}</ol>
                    );
                })}
            </ol>
        );
    }
}

export default ToDoList;
```

Comment: can you share screenshot what exactly you want?

Comment: you mean line-through as the text beside it?

Answer (score 1):

you can simply achieve this by doing this:

```
 <ol style={ completed ? {textDecoration: 'line-through'} : {textDecoration: 'none'}}>
```

just remember to change the 'completed' to a boolean relative to the item, so it can be marked if it's checked (you can achieve this by an onClick event, for example)

Answer (score 0):

You have to have the `completed` status for all of your items, it might be a little but different on how you manage that, but my code below assumes that the `completed` status will be tracked on your component state.

```
class TodoList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    list: [
      { text: "Task 1", uuid: 1 },
      { text: "Task 2", uuid: 2 },
      { text: "Task 3", uuid: 3 },
      { text: "Task 4", uuid: 4 }
    ],
    isDone: {
      "1": true,
      "2": false,
      "3": true,
      "4": false
    }
  };

  handleChange = uuid => {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      isDone: { ...this.state.isDone, [`${uuid}`]: !this.state.isDone[uuid] }
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ol>
        {this.state.list.map(item => {
          return (
            <ol
              style={{
                textDecoration: this.state.isDone[item.uuid]
                  ? "line-through"
                  : "none"
              }}
            >
              <input
                onChange={() => this.handleChange(item.uuid)}
                checked={this.state.isDone[item.uuid]}
                type="checkbox"
                key={item.uuid}
              ></input>
              {item.text}
            </ol>
          );
        })}
      </ol>
    );
  }
}

export default TodoList;
```